# edit column style of page in lightning App builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, style, app-builder

I have this App page in Lightning App builder
[image]

Each section has a custom component, could I modify the width and height of each column (2, 3) from inner components?
ex: in section 2 >> there is a component (cmp1) >> this component has a button (btn1)
section 3 >> there is a component (cmp2)
I want:
when Press btn1 >> width of section 2 become 0 (hide it ) and width of section 3 become full page width (100%)
is this bossible from cmp1 and cmp2 ?

I tried this in component css to make initial width of section 2 equal 100px, but does not work:

```
div.column.column1.THIS{
    width:100px;
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't modify the DOM outside of your own component. You'd want to write your own component that has both of the other components inside of it so you can control the layout, and place it in section 1 on the layout.

Comment: Just for the record: DOM is the language-independent model for representing and interacting with objects in HTML and XML documents.